How to align a left minipage with top and a right minipage with bottom?
I'd like to add a paramater to the items of the itemize envorinment such that the parameters is printed at the last lign of the item. See picture.

Is use two minipages, but the problem is that when the first minipage contains more than one line, the parameter is printed at the first line (top) and I want it to be at the last line (bottom) of the left minipage.
Here is my code:
\documentclass{exam}

\unframedsolutions
\printanswers

\newcommand{\element}[2][]{%
  \item \begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\textwidth}\flushleft #2 \end{minipage} \hfill
            \begin{minipage}[b]{.05\textwidth} \flushright \vspace*{\fill} #1 \end{minipage}
}   

\begin{document}

    \begin{questions}
    
        \question
        Some introduction to this question.
            \begin{parts}
                \part[3]
                This is a question which has a maximum of four points.
                    \begin{solution}\begin{itemize}
                        \element[1] { Here no problem; the sentence and the score are alligned fine  }
                        \element[1] { But when the sentance is longer and will take more than one line, the score is printed at the first line and I would like it to be printed at the last line of this part \hfill $\rightarrow$}
                        \element[1] { Fine again }
                    \end{itemize}\end{solution}
            \end{parts}

    \end{questions}
    
\end{document}


I suggest to use only one minipage and put the last argument in a \makebox set inside, but printed outside of this minipage.
The \makebox[0pt][l]{…} in the following example is used to hide the width of the inner \makebox from LaTeX and print the inner \makebox right beside the minipage.
\documentclass{exam}

\unframedsolutions
\printanswers

\newcommand{\element}[2][]{%
\item \begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\textwidth}\raggedright #2 \hfill
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[.05\textwidth][r]{#1}}
  \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{questions}
    
        \question
        Some introduction to this question.
            \begin{parts}
                \part[3]
                This is a question which has a maximum of four points.
                    \begin{solution}\begin{itemize}
                        \element[1] { Here no problem; the sentence and the score are alligned fine  }
                        \element[1] { But when the sentance is longer and will take more than one line, the score is printed at the first line and I would like it to be printed at the last line of this part \hfill $\rightarrow$}
                        \element[1] { Fine again }
                    \end{itemize}\end{solution}
            \end{parts}

    \end{questions}
    
\end{document}


Additional note: flushleft and flushright are trivlist environments (similar to center). You should not misuse them as commands. The corresponding toggles are \raggedright and \raggedleft (similar to \centering). Therefore I've replaced your \flushleft by \raggedright in the definition of \element.
